# How can I sovle slice and reshape? I got could not broadcast error

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code

```
trainPredict_dataset_like = np.ones(shape=(len(before), 5))
trainPredict_dataset_like[:,0] = before[:,0]
before = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPredict_dataset_like)[:, [0]]
before
```

I have an error as `could not broadcast input array from shape (10,1) into shape (10)`

I tried to `reshape` but it doesn't work

`before`'s shape is `(10, 1)`

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the shape of `before`? Where does the error occur?

Comment: `trainPredict_dataset_like[:,0] = before[:,0]` error occur

Comment: The shape (10, 1) array has to be changed to (10,) shape.  Double check for us: `before.shape` and `before[:,0].shape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `np.flatten()` is what you need